# Jenkins job-dsl-plugin: how to inject environment variables to an Ivy job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins Ivy job that uses the `Inject environment variables to the build process` step. I am writing a DSL script so that I can dynamically create this job with the `job-dsl-plugin` plug-in.

I set up the following lines for this:

```
steps {
  envInjectBuilder {
    propertiesFilePath('/tmp/file')
  }   
}
```

but the `steps` method can only be applied to a free-style job and not to an Ivy job. I get this in the console output:

```
Processing DSL script ivyJob.groovy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: steps cannot be applied for Ivy jobs
```

Doesn't the DSL plug-in support EnvInject for an Ivy job? If it doesn't, is there a way I can do this programmatically? I know EnvInject is compatible with Ivy jobs since I can manually create the very job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EnvInject plugin allows to inject variables at several points in a build's lifecycle. A build step is only one possibility. For a Ivy project type the job property and wrapper options will work.

```
ivyJob('example') {
  environmentVariables {
    env('ONE', '1')
    propertiesFile('env.properties')
    keepBuildVariables(true)
  }
  wrappers {
    environmentVariables {
      env('ONE', '1')
      envs(FOO: 'bar', TEST: '123')
      propertiesFile('env.properties')
    }
  }
}
```

See the Job DSL API Viewer for details:

- https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/ivyJob-environmentVariables
- https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/ivyJob-wrappers-environmentVariables

Comment: Thank you @daspilker. The `wrappers` method is what I was looking for.